# Need to push Data from MongoDB collection to .JSON file using fileSystem

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB with name "UserData". There are three records inside it, something like:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("23456"),"userName":"abc","password":"xyz","email":"x@y.com"}
{"_id":ObjectId("12345"),"userName":"def","password":"asd","email":"a@b.com"}
{"_id":ObjectId("23212"),"userName":"qwe","password":"uiw","email":"c@d.com"}
```

I want these data to be pushed into data.json file using fileSystem. I tried with my efforts of basic json data pushing approach (counting the length of data and looping into a variable and finally stringify them) but all failed.

Please help me out on this.

Thanks
Abhijeet

Comment: Could you tell what kind of problem are you going to solve?

Comment: I just want to retrieve the data in JSON file, based on which I have some data related activities to taken into account.